# Flutter Build_Runner Build Failing While Generating Mocks

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito, build-runner

Running build_runner to generate mocks using the Mockito package fails.

Terminal output:

> [INFO] Generating build script... [INFO] Generating build script
> completed, took 2.2s
>
> [INFO] Precompiling build script...... [WARNING]
> /D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mockito-5.3.0/lib/src/builder.dart:412:19:
> Error: The getter 'libraryExports' isn't defined for the class
> 'LibraryElement'.
>
> - 'LibraryElement' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart'
>   ('/D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-3.4.1/lib/dart/element/element.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
>   a getter or field named 'libraryExports'.
>   ...entryLib.libraryExports,
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mockito-5.3.0/lib/src/builder.dart:413:19:
>   Error: The getter 'libraryImports' isn't defined for the class
>   'LibraryElement'.
> - 'LibraryElement' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart'
>   ('/D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-3.4.1/lib/dart/element/element.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
>   a getter or field named 'libraryImports'.
>   ...entryLib.libraryImports,
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mockito-5.3.0/lib/src/builder.dart:1493:36:
>   Error: The getter 'enclosingElement2' isn't defined for the class
>   'ParameterElement'.
> - 'ParameterElement' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart'
>   ('/D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-3.4.1/lib/dart/element/element.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
>   a getter or field named 'enclosingElement2'.
>   final method = parameter.enclosingElement2!;
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mockito-5.3.0/lib/src/builder.dart:1524:30:
>   Error: The getter 'enclosingElement2' isn't defined for the class
>   'ParameterElement'.
> - 'ParameterElement' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart'
>   ('/D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-3.4.1/lib/dart/element/element.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
>   a getter or field named 'enclosingElement2'.
>   final method = parameter.enclosingElement2 as MethodElement;
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mockito-5.3.0/lib/src/builder.dart:1525:27:
>   Error: The getter 'enclosingElement2' isn't defined for the class
>   'MethodElement'.
> - 'MethodElement' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart'
>   ('/D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-3.4.1/lib/dart/element/element.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
>   a getter or field named 'enclosingElement2'.
>   final class_ = method.enclosingElement2 as ClassElement;
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mockito-5.3.0/lib/src/builder.dart:1535:28:
>   Error: The getter 'enclosingElement2' isn't defined for the class
>   'ExecutableElement'.
> - 'ExecutableElement' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart'
>   ('/D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-3.4.1/lib/dart/element/element.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
>   a getter or field named 'enclosingElement2'.
>   overriddenMethod.enclosingElement2 as ClassElement, name);
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mockito-5.3.0/lib/src/builder.dart:1934:23:
>   Error: The getter 'enclosingElement2' isn't defined for the class
>   'Element'.
> - 'Element' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart' ('/D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-3.4.1/lib/dart/element/element.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
>   a getter or field named 'enclosingElement2'.
>   var className = enclosingElement2!.name;
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mockito-5.3.0/lib/src/builder.dart:1937:23:
>   Error: The getter 'enclosingElement2' isn't defined for the class
>   'Element'.
> - 'Element' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart' ('/D:/flutter_windows_1.22.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-3.4.1/lib/dart/element/element.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining
>   a getter or field named 'enclosingElement2'.
>   var className = enclosingElement2!.name;
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 22.4s
>
> [SEVERE] Failed to precompile build script
> .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart. This is likely caused by a
> misconfigured builder definition.

I have tried overriding the analyzer dependency to 1.5.0 but it causes conflicts with other dependencies in the project.

Running flutter doctor shows the same errors in the terminal.

Comment: Got same error 2 hours after you posted this.

Comment: have you solved this? Both answers do not work for me.

Comment: I set 
mockito:5.2.0 
analyzer:
Started working fine after doing this.

Answer (score 9):

This is related to upgrading to mockito v5.3.0, `dart pub upgrade` might solve it. if not, revert mockito version to 5.2.0 and it should work.

`mockito: 5.2.0` without the `^`

Comment: both does not work for me. Also overriding `code_builder: ^4.2.0` as recommended here does not work for me. https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/552#issuecomment-1208973838

Comment: Make sure you write 5.2.0 without ^

Comment: And try doing flutter clean if still not fixed

Comment: writing `mockito: 5.2.0` without the `^`did the trick, thanks! :-) Maybe you could include that explicitly into your answer.

Comment: With mockito 5.3.2 the problem was solved for me.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is caused by `analyzer` package, that it's used as a dependency for `mockito`.

Seems like the new version `4.4.0` [deprecated a few APIs](https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer/changelog).

What I did to fix it for now (until maintainers fix it on the package) is to include `analyzer` as a dependency  on my `pubspec.yaml` with latest stable version `4.3.1` and it works now.

```
dev_dependencies:
  analyzer: 4.3.1
```

Hope this helps